# Google Cloud larger amount Disk I/O (operations)

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

It seems like every few weeks, our woocommerce site which hosted on Google Cloud VM instance had larger amount Disk I/O happening, which cause the server down.

The max Disk I/O is about read 56MB per second and 810 operations per second.

Could anyone let me know how could this happened and where I can find log for this, please?

Most of the time, it happens at night, please see screen grab below:

[image: screenshot]

Comment: this might be the package manager, fetching new packages (or "Windows Update")... eg, on CentOS Linux you could check with `sudo yum history`, which also shows the time.

Comment: Tried, and got this - sudo: yum: command not found, is any other comment I can try instead of yum, plz?

Comment: then there has to be `yum` available - and it has no other package manager... this also works with Cloud shell; no SSH client required (just don't run it locally, which the error message hints for). see https://cloud.google.com/shell/